# How to redirect all errors, including 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'd like all errors to go to the same error page.  I did initially try the error tag with statuscodes.  That works fine but I'd rather not have to specify so any statuscodes and still have every error go to one page.  The problem is that if I remove the statuscode entries, a 404 goes to the server's 404 page and not my error page.

Is there some way to configure all errors to go to the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to send all errors to your custom error page, and the errors that iis7 gives (not only your program)

This is something that you need to setup on II7, but you can also setup it from web.config (but actually give instructions to ii7) Here is an example

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

reference: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

Comment: You're still specifying statuscodes.  But yes - I did try that but with ExecuteURL and not a static file.  On a 404, gives a white page saying, "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

Comment: This works for me when I change 500 to 404 and use the related ExecuteURL code.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your web.config and add the customErrors element. You can then set the default redirect to a signle page

For Example

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">

</customErrors>
```

You can refer to the MSDN article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

On IIS7, you can use the new httpErrors section

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors defaultPath="Error.aspx" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

For more information
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors

Comment: I already have that.  It works fine in vs.net but not when accessing through IIS7.

Comment: Have you tried using httpErrors in the system.webserver section? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: For more information http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors